# Visualising the values of vector in watch section in vs code

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, vector

I was trying to find out the values of vector in vs code in c++. However in watch section ,the values of vector are presented as some kind of resistor which I don't want. I wanna to know exact values. How can i do that.[what my watch variable shows is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4HDO.png)

Comment: what is your debugger, try it with gdb, at least in the variables it shows the values

Comment: The first value is under the start branch.

Comment: @sweenish what about the rest of elements

Comment: @rioV8 g++.exe - Build and debug active file

Comment: They're there. You could also use the debug terminal.

Comment: no problems with gdb debugging/viewing `std::vector` in variables and watch, follow the instructions in the VSC doc to the letter